# sonarqube disable weak sslv3 cipher

Tags: sonarqube, poodle-attack, sslv3

I am running Sonarqube 4.0 over SSL.  I would like to disable the vulnerable SSLv3 protocol and only allow TLSv1 or higher.  Is this possible? If so, what setting needs to change?

Answer (score 0):

SSLv3 will be disabled in 4.5.2 : https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-5860